# are multiplication and division operators supported by alloy?

Tags: alloy

I am wondering if multiplication and division operators are supported by Alloy. I tried "*" as multiplication operator, but it does not work. "+" works though.

Thanks a lot.
Sincerely,
Fathiyeh

Answer (score 3):

The arithmetic operators are supported by means of built-in functions: `plus`/`add`, `minus`/`sub`, `mul`, `div`, `rem`.

```
one sig S {
  x, y: Int,
  pres, sres, mres, rres, dres: Int
} {
  pres = plus[x, y]
  sres = sub[x, y]
  mres = mul[x, y]
  rres = rem[x, y]
  dres = div[x, y]
}

run {}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Aleksandar. That really helped.

Comment: I am wondering if other datatypes like floating numbers are also supported? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Floats are not supported.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to write a code to find two integers that their division is less than 2/3? or because 2/3 is not integer, it cannot support it, and for example return 1 and 2 as result?

Comment: @Fathiyeh That's really a separate question, but you can represent floats as rational numbers via a new signature with numerator and denominator and write comparison functions for them.

Answer (score 0):

From [Software Abstractions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262017156) (2006 edition) by Daniel Jackson, p. 135, the answer in the discussion around multiplication states "No, it doesn't" and goes on to explain that models that require this are often not well suited to modelling in Alloy.